# exclude directories with the same name ending

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to write a shell script that runs commands on all folders except the ones with  names ending with "_long" and "_wavs".

This is what I have tried:

```
dirs=($(find /Volumes/exchange -type d))

for dir in "${dirs[@]}/!(`basename "$dir"`_long|`basename "$dir"`_wavs)/";
do
   *commands*
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop with `find` excluding dirs with certain names :

```
for dir in $(find /Volumes/exchange -type d ! -name "*_wavs" ! -name "*_long") 
do  
    # commands on "$dir"  
done
```

Answer (score 2):

When you can't modify the input like the excellent answer of @nullPointer, you can check inside the loop:

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
   [[ $dir =~ _long$|_wavs$ ]] && continue;
   *commands*
done
```